# Extraction from .DLL file, only ending up with files with no formats

Tags: dll, extract

I am a beginner of extracting from .DLL files and i have a problem.
I found files to work on my personal project in the .DLL and when i pressed "Save [number] sources", it only ends up with files with no file format.

Please answer if i'm doing something wrong, thank you!

Software: dnSpy v6.1.8

I tried converting it to .png files and it didn't work. I expected it to extract as .PNG files but it extracted it as files with no file format

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read tour for what kind of questions belong here, "how to use .dnSpy v6.1.8" probably belongs at SuperUser.com  My guess is you are extracting BMP  or ICO files, but you would need to use a hex editor to look at the first block of the file to see the format.   Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.